# Cannot enable Windows Features (like .NET 3.5 and Subsystem for Linux) through PowerShell or Control Panel

Tags: windows-10, powershell, .net-framework, .net-3.5

I can’t enable Windows features through the Control Panel, features on demand, downloading them online, or through the Command Line or PowerShell. It fails with error code 0x80070002. I think it can’t find the files and I tried running a command to restore system files but after searching multiple sites I can’t fix it. I can provide any more information you need, I just need help activating these features. I have another computer which works fine so if I need to copy files over I can do that if you can tell me which ones. Thanks!

Edit: Thanks for the feedback
. I will clarify some things. First, my Windows information is: Windows 10 Enterprise, Version 1803, OS build 17134.472. Next, I tried to turn both .NET 3.5 and Subsystem for Linux on through Windows Features and it still failed with error code 0x80070002.  As for the command I ran, it was sfc /scannow

Comment: What build of Windows 10 are you using?  Edit your question to include this vital information.  **I tried running a command** - Which command?

Comment: What command did you use to attempt to install either of these Windows Feature?  Edit your question.

Answer (score 0):

Its because those are not in the Control Panel. ***they're in Windows Features*** and the install has changed for WSL a bit.

Just hit the Windows key and type Windows Features to get to them.

> Windows Subsystem for Linux Installation Guide for Windows 10
>
> https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/wsl/install-win10

Comment: I did go to the Windows Features through the Control Panel and by searching for it, my problem is when I try to enable any features, it gives me an error. I have tried to enable the same things on a different computer without any problems, so the issue is with this specific computer, not what I'm doing.

Comment: OK, so, really an environmental issue. Can you reset the machine back to a previous date, or reset the machine holistically?

Comment: I can't reset the machine back, but how would I "reset the machine holistically"?